# Nlog send by exchange

Tags: c#, logging, exchange-server, nlog

I am attempting to use NLog in a C# application that is deployed over a local domain.

Each user has an exchange mailbox and up until now I have been using Office.Interop with a basic logging class to send the results from their built in exchange account.

Is there any way to do something similar with NLog, I cant see anything in their documentation that would allow me to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the NLog [Mail Target](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Mail-target) in combination, with (a) the [Windows Identity Layout Renderer](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Windows-Identity-Layout-Renderer) (if you can construct the mailaddress from the logged in username)

```xml
<!-- In your NLog.config. -->
<target
    ...
    from="${windows-identity:domain=false}@yourcompany.com"
    ...>
```

or (b) the [EventProperties Layout Renderer](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/EventProperties-Layout-Renderer) (formerly EventContext) to provide the mailaddress from your application.

```
/* In your code. */
LogEventInfo theEvent = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Debug, "", "Pass my custom value");

theEvent.Properties["MailAddress"] = theUsersMailAddress;
myLogger.Log(theEvent);
```

```xml
<!-- In your NLog.config. -->
<target
    ...    
    from="${event-properties:item=MailAddress}"
    ...>
```